# Error: Status Update failed while sharing from facebook

Tags: android

I am using below code :-

```
 FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
 callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
        shareDialog = new ShareDialog(this);


    if (ShareDialog.canShow(ShareLinkContent.class)) {
        ShareLinkContent linkContent = new ShareLinkContent.Builder()
                .setContentTitle("Hello Facebook")
                .setContentDescription(
                        "The 'Hello Facebook' sample  showcases simple Facebook integration")
                .setContentUrl(Uri.parse("http://www.google.com"))
                .build();

        shareDialog.show(linkContent, ShareDialog.Mode.AUTOMATIC);
    }
```

compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.9.0'

Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Comment: Also it is showing toast :-"We are sorry this post is not longer available. It may have been removed."

Answer (score 0):

Had similar issue, make sure that com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationName from manifest matches Display Name from facebook dev app settings.

```
<meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationName"android:value="Display Name" />
```